# how to play radio channel over http on mediaplayer object?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to play radio channel through http on mediaplayer object but its not working (blank screen appears)

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
                primaryStage.setTitle("Embedded Media Player");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 241);
URL channel=new URL ("http://178.33.178.204:9322/stream?type=http&nocache=353");
Media media= new Media(channel.toString());
MediaPlayer player= new MediaPlayer(media);
Button play= new Button("play");
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player); 
player.setAutoPlay(true);
root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
}
```

i tried to play local its working and video also 
but when i try to play it through my code its local video and audio works but http not working

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request that you are providing in the `MediaPlayer` constructor seems to be the issue. The JavaFX MediaPlayer documentation should provide information for the supported file types.

EDIT: See if the MediaPlayer is returning any errors.

```
player.setOnError(new Runnable() {    
@Override
public void run() {
    String message = player.errorProperty().get().getMessage();
    System.out.println(message);
}});
```

Comment: Yes may be its the issue but i need the solution for how to play it?

Comment: See the edit in my original answer. Let me know if an error is printed to console.

Comment: Yes its returning this:
[com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@26375dc6] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID

Comment: I think this is a common issue and no one ever solve this until now even oracle says that they support http on media player but its not.
is their anyone from oracle can help us on that?

Comment: It looks like a similar JIRA has already been filed for this issue. In the meantime, your program could copy the stream to a local temporary directory then set the media source as the local file.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do copy the stream to work on my local machine?